# Any way to write a unit test framework in Scheme without either apply or macros?

Tags: unit-testing, scheme

I am wondering if there is a way to write a test framework (a very small one, just as an interesting example of Scheme code) that uses neither APPLY nor macros. I suppose not, since any test framework would need to at least get a list of arguments and apply procedures to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that if you only use thunks for computations that you want to test.  But both macros and `apply` will generally make it more convenient to use and to implement.  (You should probably also have a look at the number of lightweight testing frameworks floating around.)

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote such a thing: https://github.com/yawaramin/ggspec/tree/8f88d4641ab603b42510b88bdb3ebaed699d4803

Used a lot of thunks everywhere. Not very elegant from the perspective of the API user. But I since re-implemented it using macros, which made it a lot more convenient to use.